# need assistance on making search feature work in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component

So I have an component called Form, this component enables live search based on user input,
 [image: Form Component]

the Form Component will have to be rendered inside a Search component, this is a screenshot of it

[image: Search Component]

On my App.js I am giving the Search component a prop thst contains a function called performSearch

[image: Giving Search component a function as prop]

However, when I try to submit the search input I get this error:

[image: React Error]

Can someone please help

Comment: Please post code as text, not as pictures.

Comment: I was going to do that, but then this website gave me a warning that I shouldn’t use most of the space writing syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass as many prop as you want to your component in a single render i.e. 
While you are rendering the Search Component pass the `onSearch` prop like this:

```
  <Route
    exact
    path="/search"
    render={() => (
      <Search
        onSearch={this.performSearch}
        data={this.state.pics}
      />
    )}
  />
```

If you pass prop like this, it is never going to find the prop `onSearch` in the component since It is rendering the first match and it does not have any prop `onSearch`

this is incorrect approach:

```
  <Route
    exact
    path="/search"
    render={() => <Search  data={this.state.pics} />}
  />
  <Route
    exact
    path="/search"
    component={() => <Search onSearch={this.performSearch} />}
  />
```

For your reference you can check this : https://codesandbox.io/s/llk96nk5l

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, although I noticed that for some reason my Home component's pictures combine with the pictures of my other navlinks, did that happen to you too?

Comment: I did a commit so that you could see what I am talking about, well if you'd like to see that is, it happens when you click on cats, dogs and computers